# Can Windows 7 automatically maintain a clone of another directory?

Tags: windows-7

I'm working on a Git repo for a client and I want to keep my client repos separate from my Apache htdocs folder. I want to work on the repo files here:

C:\Web\Clients\repolocation

And whenever I save a file there, I want the clone to be updated here:

C:\xampp\htdocs\clientrepo

Is this sort of thing possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for [directory Junctions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/) which is similar to a linux symbolic link. Strictly, it is not 2 copies but the same copy referenced by 2 paths with separate permissions.(similar to how documents and settings points to users)

Comment: In the same vain, on windows 7 (well since Vista) you can use mklink to create a symlink

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I'm going to edit your answer to provide the syntax that works with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try Microsoft [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52).  It doesn't maintain the copy in realtime, but you can set up a scheduled task to sync them on whatever schedule you like (at logon, every hour, etc.)